# Twitter feeds from User BlackBerry 10

Tags: twitter, blackberry-10

How to get Twitter feeds from User and place them in List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the twittertimeline example on github, which shows how to do this using the Native Cascades API in C++ and QML:

http://blackberry.github.com/Cascades-Samples/twittertimeline.html (detailed walkthrough)

https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/twittertimeline (repository)

It shows exactly how to use the JSON api to retrieve the tweets of a user, load them into a datamodel and display them using either standard or custom list elements.

Note: It uses the older twitter 1.0 REST API.

Comment: Sir, this is outstanding. Thanks!